# show that $ \ f'(x_1)>0 \ \ and \ \ f'(x_2) <0 \ $

Tags: derivatives

Let  $ f $ be differentiable on  $(a,b) $ and continuous on $ [a,b] $ with  $ f(a)=f(b)=0 .$ Prove that if $ f(c)≠0 $ for some $ c∈(a,b) $  , there exists  $ x_1,x_2∈(a,b) $ such that $ \ f'(x_1)>0 \ \ and \ \ f'(x_2) <0 \ $

**Answer:**

By Rolle's theorem ,we have

$ f'(c)=0 \ $ for some $ c \in (a,b) \ $

Hence there exists $ x_1 , \ x_2 \in (a,b) \ $ such that $ \ f'(x_1)>0 \ \ and \ \ f'(x_2) <0 \ $

Comment: Not following.  How does that fact that the derivative at some $c$ vanishes imply the existence of the two $x_i$ you seek?  Note:  it is very confusing to use $c$ to mean two different things.

Comment: why is that?...

Comment: Hint: Using Rolle's theorem, if $f'(c) = 0$ then $\text{sign} (f'(c+\varepsilon)) = -\text{sign}(f'(c-\varepsilon))$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there exists $f(c) \gt 0$ the curve lies above the x axis with upward sloping somewhere along the curve from point a in the x-axis as  $f(a) =0$ and to reach again point b in the x-axis $f(b) =0$, it should be downward sloping somewhere along the curve.  This upward sloping and downward sloping of the curve ensures there exists some $x_1$ such that $f'(x_1) \gt 0$ and some $x_2$ such that $f'(x_2) \lt0$.

The opposite is true when $f(c)\lt 0$.

Comment: That answer is an intuitive explanation of MVT.

Answer (score 2):

you can use MVT (i.e. Lagrange’s theorem)

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem

e.g.

$f(c)-f(a)=f’(x_1)(c-a)>0$ for some $x_1\in(a,b)$ thus $f’(x_1) >0$

and

$f(b)-f(c)=f’(x_2)(b-c)<0$ for some $x_2\in(a,b)$ thus $f’(x_2) <0$

Answer (score 1):

We can assume that $f(c)>0$. Let $x_0 \in [a,b]$ such that $f(x_0) = \max_{x \in [a,b]}f(x)$. Then we have

$f(x_0) \ge f(c) >0, x_0 \in (a,b)$ and $f'(x_0)=0$.

Now suppose that $f'(x)\le 0$ for all $x \in (a,x_0)$. The $f$ is  decreasing in $[a,x_0)$, hence $f(x_0) \le f(a)=0$, a contradiction.

Therefore, $f'(x_1)>0$ for some $x_1 \in (a,x_0)$.

In the same manner we get some $x_2 \in (x_0,b)$ such that $f'(x_2) <0$.